# Accessing properties of objects in array to display in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, arrays, object, properties, uitableview

I am using an XML parser to get information from a blog to create a feed reader app. I created an object with properties that are the data for each blog entry (title, published, author...). I'm storing the data in the object, then using a pointer to put the object in an array of parsed data.  When I go to access the properties to display them in my UITableView, every cell is the same, with the last blog entry's data for every one.

parser .m file

```
@interface Parser()

//This property holds the blog objects that were parsed
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *parsedResults;

//This property holds the current element content being parsed
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentElement;

@property (nonatomic, strong) FRFeedItem *blogEntry;

@end


@implementation SolsticeParser

@synthesize parsedResults = _parsedResults;
@synthesize currentElement = _currentElement;

// Will be used to truncate data parsed from publish tag so that it will only store the YYYY-MM-DD to self.blogEntry.datepublished
NSRange dateOnly = {0, 10};

//This method initializes the parser, sets the delegate, starts parsing, and returns the results.
- (NSMutableArray *)parseFeedWithResults:(NSURL *)URL
{
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:URL];
parser.delegate = self;
self.parsedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[parser parse];             // Everything parsed here
return self.parsedResults;
}
```

...Here parsed data is saved to the properties of the BlogEntry object...

```
#pragma mark - Parser delegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
 namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

// Custom blog object initialized here
     if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
        if (!self.blogEntry) {
            self.blogEntry = [[FRFeedItem alloc] init];

        }
    }

}
...

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if([elementName isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    self.blogEntry.title = self.currentElement;

} else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"published"]) {
    self.blogEntry.datePublished = [self.currentElement substringWithRange:dateOnly];

} else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"entry"]) {
    [self.parsedResults  addObject:self.blogEntry];
}
}
```

In MyTableViewController.m:

```
@interface MyTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) Parser* parser;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* feedDataFromParser;

@end

@implementation MyTableViewController

 // synthesize automatically done by Xcode v4.6

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.parser = [[Parser alloc] init]; // initialize parser by allocating memory on the heap
[self loadItems]; // automatically loads data to be displayed upon opening the app

}

- (void)loadItems
{
// information parsed from blog stored to a mutable array
self.feedDataFromParser = [self.parser parseFeedWithResults:[NSURL URLWithString:kFeedURL]];
}

...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//code not included for this question for brevity

// Configure the cell from data stored in mutable array of FRFeedItem objects
// PROBLEM:
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.feedDataFromParser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.feedDataFromParser objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] datePublished];

return cell;
}
@end
```

As far as I can tell, there is nothing syntactically wrong.  I've tried printing out the data parsed and saved to the object in the parser file as well as the value of indexPath.row, and both are correct.
What am I missing??

Comment: What is the error you have got?

Comment: Where and how do you create feedDataFromParser? If you log it, does it only show one object?

Comment: @VishnuPrasath There are no errors. The problem is that when I run the simulator, the table has the appropriate number of cells (equal to the number of blog entries parsed), but all of them are the same (namely, the last blog entry parsed).

Comment: @rdelmar It is declared in MyTableViewController.m as such `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* feedDataFromParser;`. Its content is the array that is returned from the parsing: `self.feedDataFromParser = [self.parser parseFeedWithResults:[NSURL URLWithString:kFeedURL]];`

Comment: How do you create it I asked -- show the code. Also, what about the log? What does logging it show?

Comment: So it should be the same as parsedResults? Is that the one you said you logged and its ok?

Comment: @mrauh if only last blog entry shows in cell then the issue is in adding the objects to array.. Check the Array init section... It probably init each time when next blog entry is passed.

Comment: @VishnuPrasath, no that can't be it, or he would only have a count of one in the array -- he says he has the right count.

Comment: @rdelmar Oh!.. I didnt look at that... :{

Comment: When you logged parsedResults, can you see that all the blogEntry objects are different? I don't see where you create a new blogEntry object each time through the parser.

Comment: @rdelmar I just learned obj-c, so I'm not sure how to log the objects to check if they are different (and they should be the same type, just different properties). I am adding more code so hopefully you can see how the objects are created

Comment: If you do NSLog(@"%@",self.feedDataFromParser) it should print out all the objects with an address next to them, like <BlogEntry: 0x7678940; Are all the numbers the same?

Comment: @rdelmar Yes, they are all the same :( (thank you for the NSLog help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is this line:

```
if (!self.blogEntry)
```

After you create the first one, you won't create any more. Try removing that if clause, and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you SO much...it would have taken me hours more to figure that out. Worked 100%